# Cordova iOS: Alert-Popups and Device-Ready is not firing

Tags: ios, cordova

I just set up a new PhoneGap project for android, which worked perfectly fine without any problems, there were almost no changes to the template project.

Then I wanted to move that exact project to iOS, and the woes began.

When I start the project, suddenly a bunch of alter dialogs pop up, with device information, network status. Each offer me "ok" and "cancel". When I press "ok" on any of them, execution is halted, and nothing happens further.

When I cancel them all, I get to the project screen, where it says "connecting to device". Obviously, `deviceready` is never fired on this.

Since this project is merely the template offered by Cordova themselves, I find it hard to believe it is not supposed to run. I suspect the `console.log` messages get popped up on screen rather than the XCode debug window.

I am completely new to XCode or any iOS programming (hence PhoneGap), and I would appreciate any help.

Using Cordova 2.8.1.

Comment: Probably not the answer you want to hear but invest some time and make a native iOS app written in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason was I mistakenly copies the `cordova.js` for android into the ios project, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693449/no-device-ready-and-no-console-log-with-xcode-using-cordova-1-5).

Comment: had the exact same problem, and couldn't figure out why... thanks!